# brew install llvm, and the build process is very slow

Tags: homebrew, llvm

Excuse me, I use the command: brew install llvm, and the build process is very slow. Is there any way to speed it up? My computer configuration is 2020 Mac Inter 8G
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nB75L.png)

Excuse me, I use the command: brew install llvm, and the build process is very slow. Is there any way to speed it up? My computer configuration is 2020 Mac Inter 8G

Comment: Could you please provide output of the brew command? If it is the first time that you are using brew most probably it is doing an auto-update of all outdated software. Disable this behaviour before installing llvm:
Set env variable HOMEBREW_NO_AUTO_UPDATE=1 by running in terminal:
export HOMEBREW_NO_AUTO_UPDATE=1

Comment: Please provide code or output details so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.